# what are wss and moss libraries available in .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint

In .net framework. what are libraries available for working in sharepoint and their uses

Comment: Don't you mean which namespaces are available?
If you install Sharepoint, the most common namespace/dll you'll use is the Microsoft.Sharepoint, which is to be found on this location: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll' (default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no libraries in the .net framework intented for working with SharePoint

But when you install SharePoint there is a lot of .net libraries which allows you to do everything you can do through the UI and more. But these only work for programs running on the server.

In SharePoint versions prior to 2010 you also have a series of Web Services, RPC and HTTP request options for working with SharePoint from an other machine.

In SharePoint 2010 this has been extended with a Client Side Object Model and a REST interface.

Comment: Just a quick addition to Per's answer in case you don't have SP and want to create web parts... The majority of Web Parts developed for SharePoint use a Namespace in the ASP.Net framework. There is a web part namespace that is part of SharePoint, but as a general rule you should not use.